# Suffix “er”: a person who does something

Tags: nouns

For example, “violinist” means a person who plays the violin.

It’s not a general truth or a general fact that I play the violin, and I don’t play violin habitually, but I’m just try playing violin now.

In this case, can I call myself who’s playing violin now “violinist”?

Comment: Your title and your question body don't match...

Comment: I suggest you try your own language. Can you not be a "violinist" and play the violin? Can you do biology and not be a biologist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I will take some liberties and make some presumptions as to what your are really trying to say.

*I am trying to learn the violin and so sometimes I play the violin. In this case, can I call myself, "who’s is now playing a violin", a “violinist”?*

---

> Well technically yes, because according to my dictionary; *violinist; a person who plays a violin*

But most Truck drivers would not call themselves a Trucker until they passed their test and were employed driving a truck. Most people who are learning or not accomplished in a particular skill would acknowledge that fact and term themselves:

***Apprentice, Student, beginner, learner, amateur or something similar.***

---

**violinist** [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/violinist)noun [ C ] UK  a person who plays a violin

Answer (score 2):

In general I would say that "violinist" (or any other musical term like that) carries a sense of some proficiency and regularity and perhaps even professionalism. If you just started playing the violin last week you should not go to a dinner party and introduce yourself by saying "I am a violinist." Instead you could say (for example, if someone asks what your hobbies are) "I play the violin."

But in some contexts you could use it, like if you are in a group of musicians. For example: You are in high school and you play violin in the school orchestra. You go to a competition and meet some musicians from another school. They ask what you play and you say "I'm a violinist." That would be acceptable even though you are not a professional musician.

Comment: Sry You had not posted when I started writing and I just posted when I completed my answer.